# Mutiple operations in Async Task (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpclient

Is it possible to have multiple httpclient inside an asynctask? In my code below.. it retrieves the info of the user then displays it into a new activity..But I also wanted to get the number of followers and following of the user when ProfileAsync is executed..i have separate php files for the retrieving of user info and the number of followers and followings..

```
class ProfileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

                private Dialog loadingDialog;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(HomePageActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                    String json=null;
                    String json2=null;
                    byte[] data;
                    StringBuffer buffer = null;
                    InputStream is = null;



                    try{
                        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", uname));

                        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        json = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                        Log.e("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    return json;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String json){
                    super.onPostExecute(json);

                    loadingDialog.dismiss();

                    try
                    {
                    jsonobject = new JSONObject(json);
                    jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("user");
                    JSONObject jb= jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
                    //Username = jb.getString("Username");
                    Password = jb.getString("Password");
                    Fullname = jb.getString("Fullname");
                    Email = jb.getString("Email");
                    Bio = jb.getString("Bio");
                    Location = jb.getString("Location");



                    fn.setText(Fullname);
                    em.setText(Email);
                    loc.setText(Location);
                    b.setText(Bio);

                    if(json!=null)
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(HomePageActivity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra(u.username(), u.getUsername());
                        i.putExtra("password",Password);
                        i.putExtra("fullname",Fullname);
                        i.putExtra("email", Email);
                        i.putExtra("bio", Bio);
                        i.putExtra("location", Location);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }



                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            }//end of profileasynctask
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can send multiple urls as params, all the urls will available as params array like params[0], params[1] and you can loop through it to send multiple requests but i suggest to not do it in a single AyncTask because it will take a significant amount of time and as described on Android Developer guide, AsyncTask should be used for short operations that require a worker thread, you can read about it here - 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

If you want to send multiple request try using famous network libraries like retrofit or if you want to use AsynTask, code a separate task for each request.